# How to make transparent part on non-transparent user control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, transparency

On my MainWindow.xaml there are user control tiles, Background of each of them is set like this:

```
ucTile.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Some);
```

depending on various user settings.

Now I want to add a new feature to my app: **the possibility of setting an custom background image for main window**.

*But I need some part of my tiles to be transparent, to show the image, that is under them.* Like this:

[image: window example]

This is how my tiles look now:

[image: tiles]

How to achieve that? I can not to set my ucTile background to transparent, because if should remain to be colored. **Is there maybe some component inf WPF that would act as "hole" showing what is under non-transparent element?**

Comment: You could set a PNG as a background image. PNG supports transparency.

Comment: How exactly is "part of my tiles ... transparent" defined? Perhaps add an image that shows what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Clemens I added the image, hope it will be clear now.

Comment: That looks like a Path with Stroke and Fill and an appropriate Geometry. Is there anything else in that control, e.g. some text?

Comment: Sorry, I won't download that. Post the image here.

Comment: @Clemens Added.

Comment: Opacity/OpacityMask maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<Window Background="Transparent">
    <Polygon Fill="LightBlue"/>
</Window>
```

You will need to add `Points` to get the desired shape !

Read more about Polygon [here!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's some details since some1 feels like downvoting for no obvious reason is good ...

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.FolderControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Polygon Fill="Red"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Points="0,0 , 50,0 , 55,10 , 100,10 , 100,80 , 0,80 " />
    <Image Source="if_desktop_83651.png" Margin="5,20,5,5" Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
    <Border Background="Green"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Caption" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Window**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Background="Green">
<local:FolderControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Pros:**

- You can do any shape you want

**Cons:**

- Won't resize -> Calculate `Points` in Code

Comment: Thanksfor good solution, @Felix D. Polygon is really good for me in this case.

Comment: @Gabriel glad it helped !

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Path element for the UserControl's outline in its ControlTemplate. The Path's `Fill`, `Stroke` and `StrokeThickness` properties are bound to the UserControl's `Background`, `BorderBrush` and (newly defined) `OutlineThickness`, so you can set them as usual.

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.Tile" ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Tile">
            <Grid>
                <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                      StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding OutlineThickness}"
                      Data="{TemplateBinding Outline}"/>

                <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Path binds to two dependency property of the Tile control:

```
public partial class Tile : UserControl
{
    public Tile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Outline), typeof(Geometry), typeof(Tile));

    public Geometry Outline
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(OutlineProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(OutlineThickness), typeof(double), typeof(Tile), 
            new PropertyMetadata(1.0, (o, e) => ((Tile)o).UpdateOutline()));

    public double OutlineThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        UpdateOutline();
    }

    private void UpdateOutline()
    {
        var geometry = new StreamGeometry();
        var size = RenderSize;
        var border = OutlineThickness / 2d;

        using (var sgc = geometry.Open())
        {
            sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(border, border), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(size.Width - 20, border), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(size.Width - border, 20), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(size.Width - border, size.Height - border), true, true);
            sgc.LineTo(new Point(0, size.Height - border), true, true);
        }

        Outline = geometry;
    }
}
```

Now extend the `UpdateOutline` method as necessary.

---

In case the XAML designer complains about the TargetType of the ControlTemplate, you may as well use this:

```
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <Grid>
            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                  StrokeThickness="{Binding OutlineThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  Data="{Binding Outline, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

            <ContentPresenter
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```